# How to use numbers as a whole in regular expressions

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have some Chinese addresses, and I want to extract strings by regular expressions.I want to get it like:

```
"商城1栋11楼1112室 " #return <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(7, 12), match='1112室'>
```

My idea is to remove the format that satisfies "栋 + number + (楼|单元)". I used `(栋+[0-9]*(?!楼|单元))` to do it, but it separates the numbers. As follow:

```
>>>ms = re.finditer(re.compile("(栋+[0-9]*(?!楼|单元))|([0-9]+室)"),"商城1栋11楼1112室")
```

The result is that:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(3, 5), match='栋1'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(7, 12), match='1112室'>
```

How do I achieve the goal of using numbers as a whole?

More examples:

```
"商城1栋1112"  #return <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(3, 8), match='栋1112'>
"商城1栋23单元1112室"  #return <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(8, 13), match='1112室'>
```

It may be a little difficult to understand, but I also hope that someone can help solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your expected output?

Comment: @HenryYik The output I expect is the retun behind. For example,I expect is `'栋1112'` for `"商城1栋1112"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `(栋+[0-9]*(?!楼|单元))|([0-9]+室)`, the first alternative will match `栋` followed by a number not followed by `楼` nor by `单元`. But that's not sufficient; you also want the `[0-9]*` to match as many digits as possible, which means it must not be followed by a digit either. Otherwise, as you observe, it will match `栋1` in `栋11`: the `栋1` is followed by a `1`, which is not either of the forbidden follow sequences.

Consequently, you need to add digits to the list of things which cannot follow:

```
(栋+[0-9]*(?![0-9]|楼|单元))|([0-9]+室)
```

It's possible that the `[0-9]*` should be `[0-9]+`, since `[0-9]*` will cheerfully match an empty string.

Comment: I think this pattern should be modified because it does not match anything in `商城1元1112`

Comment: @unbearablelightness: that's true, it diesn't. Should it? I don't see that case in the question and I have no idea what the symbols mean.

Comment: Yeah, no idea about the meaning of the symbol, I don't speak Chinese either. However from looking at the string `元1112室` in the OP I would say that there is a possibility than the symbol `元` can precede digits.

Comment: @unbearable lightness: i read that example as including the to-be-ignored `栋23单元` but that was just a guess based on OP's original regex. I'll wait for confirmation from OP. (Hard to read this thread without thinking about John Searle.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a conditional statement:

```
(\D\d{4}$)?(?(1)|(\d{4}\D))
```

- `(\D\d{4}$)` First capture group. A non digit `D`, followed by four digits `\d{4}` at end of string `$`.
- `?` Make preceding pattern optional.
- `(?(1)` Conditional statement, if capture group one exists, match no more.
- `|(\d{4}\D))` OR `|`, match and capture four digits `\d{4}` followed by a non digit `\D`.

You can try the pattern [here](https://regex101.com/r/8PhGLV/1).

---

Alternatively you could speed up the regex slightly with the pattern:

```
([栋元]\d{4}$)?(?(1)|(\d{4}[元室]))
```

Which checks for characters `栋` or `元` only rather than any non digit `\D`.

You can try the pattern [here](https://regex101.com/r/8PhGLV/3).

---

In Python:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile('(\D\d{4}$)?(?(1)|(\d{4}\D))')

print(re.search(pattern,'商城1栋11楼1112室'))
print(re.search(pattern,'商城1栋1112'))
print(re.search(pattern,'商城1栋23单元1112室'))
```

Prints:

```
re.Match object; span=(7, 12), match='1112室'>
<re.Match object; span=(3, 8), match='栋1112'>
<re.Match object; span=(8, 13), match='1112室'>
```

Comment: I have a question about how to deal with different lengths of number.

Comment: You mean more than four digits? My pattern is correct for what you show in your OP.

Comment: Yes, your method can also be done for my OP. I'm just curious about how to deal with it.

Comment: You can just change the pattern to `(\D\d+$)?(?(1)|(\d+\D$))`. See [here](https://regex101.com/r/8PhGLV/2). Does that help?

Comment: The method is so great.